# Creating a handler for liquidsoap fallback

Tags: fallback, liquidsoap

I would like to know when liquidsoap has fallback to the emergency_playlist so that I can initiate a system script. perhaps there is a handler that can do this similar to on_blank(handler,radio),

here is my code,

```
#!/home/ubuntu/.opam/system/bin/liquidsoap
myplaylist = playlist("~/backup_playlist/playlist/Emergency-list.m3u",mode="normal")
backup_playlist = audio_to_stereo(myplaylist) 
liveset = input.http("http://listen.qkradio.com.au:8382/main_test.mp3")
radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false,
         [strip_blank(max_blank=120.,liveset), backup_playlist])
radio = on_blank(handler,radio)

 # Stream it out
output.icecast(
%mp3(bitrate=64),
host="localhost", port=8382, password="xxxxxxxx", 
mount="test.mp3",  radio)
```

**Update:**

the following code below does execute a system script however only when the script starts up, I would like however this to be executed every time a fallback is initiated

```
def fall()
   system("./scripts/pushover.py")
   backup_playlist
end

radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false,
         [strip_blank(max_blank=10.,liveset), fall() , security])
```